# Maximizing a product of vectors and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, optimization

I have a function of the form

$$ f(\xi) = v^T \left( S + \xi^2 D \right)^{-1} u $$

I would like to find the critical points of this function (if there are any) on the domain $\xi \in [0,\infty)$.  More specifically, I want to find the maximum of $|f(\xi)|$.  $v$ and $u$ are column vectors, $S$ is an invertible matrix, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.  I'm not really sure how to go about it -- normally, I would take the derivative with respect to $\xi$ and then set it to 0 and solve for $\xi$, but I'm not sure how the derivatives would work with the matrix inverse and the vector-matrix and dot products.

**EDIT2:** Revisiting this problem again.  Using the formula for the derivative of an inverse (http://planetmath.org/derivativeofinversematrix), I get:

$$ 0 = f'(\xi) = - 2\xi v^T ( S + \xi^2 D)^{-1} D ( S + \xi^2 D)^{-1} u \tag{1} $$

From the physics of the problem, I know that one critical point is at $\xi = 0$ and also that $f(0) = 0$.  However, from numerical experiments, it seems that $(f(\xi))^2$ has a nonzero global (and local) maximum somewhere else in the domain.  My question now is how do I solve Equation (1) for nonzero values of $\xi$?  Any help would be appreciated!

Some properties of the given quantities:

(1) The diagonal of $S$ is strictly positive ($>0$), while the off-diagonal entries of $S$ are all non-positive ($\le 0$).

(2)  All of the entries of $u$ are non-negative.

(3) $||u||_1 = \sum\limits_i u_i = 1$

(4) The entries of the diagonal matrix $D$ are all strictly positive.

(5) For all $i$, $\sum\limits_j s_{ji} \ge 0$.  This bounds how negative the off-diagonal entries of $S$ can be.

(6) If it helps, $f(\xi)$ can be viewed as the only nonzero eigenvalue of the matrix $(S+\xi^2 D)^{-1} uv^T$.  It is also the trace of this matrix since the trace is equal to the sum of all the eigenvalues, and there is only one nonzero eigenvalue.

(7) All scalars, vector entries, and matrix entries are real.

(8) The entries of $(S + \xi^2 D)^{-1}u$ are all non-negative.

Any thoughts you have on this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My research has led me to revisit this problem recently and, from some numerical trials on Mathematica, it seems that there are some nonzero (i.e., $\xi \ne 0$) critical points.  Moreover, for many cases of interest, $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: In view of property (6), does the [Bauer-Fike theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer%E2%80%93Fike_theorem) could bring something ?

Comment: That's an interesting theorem that I haven't heard of before.  However, I'm not sure if it can bring anything especially useful for this particular problem -- it provides a bound for the eigenvalues of a perturbed matrix relative to the eigenvalues of the original matrix, but I'm looking for the true value of the eigenvalue.

Comment: Looking more closely to this property (6), shouldn't it be $f(\xi)$ is the **trace** of $(S+\xi^2 D)^{-1} uv^T$ ?

Comment: You might be right about it being the trace, but here's why it's the eigenvalue: Start with the eigenvalue problem $\lambda x = (S+\xi^2D)^{-1} uv^T x$.  Rearrange to get $\lambda  (S+\xi^2D) x = uv^T x$.  $uv^T$ is a rank 1 matrix whose image is spanned by $u$. Thus, any eigenvector $x$ must be a multiple of $(S+\xi^2D)^{-1}u$.  If we substitute in $x = (S+\xi^2D)^{-1}u$, we have $\lambda u = u (v^T (S+\xi^2D)^{-1} u)$.  Summing the entries of both sides and using property (3) yields $\lambda = f(\xi)$.

Comment: Actually, yes you are also correct.  The specified matrix has exactly one nonzero eigenvalue given by $f(\xi)$.  Since the trace of the matrix is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, the trace is also equal to $f(\xi)$.  I've updated property (6) to emphasize that $f(\xi)$ is the only nonzero eigenvalue.

Comment: That's right. I understand now that it's due to the fact that $uv^T$ is a rank one matrix. Besides, I arrived at the conclusion of the trace by another way, by using the fact that, in a product of 3 matrices $tr(ABC)=tr(CAB)=tr(BCA)$.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, define the matrix $M$ and its differential
$$\eqalign{
 M &= S+\xi^2D \cr
dM &= 2D\xi\,d\xi\cr\cr
}$$
Now write the function in terms of the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product and this new variable.  In this form, it is easy to find the differential and gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= vu^T:M^{-1} \cr\cr
df &= -vu^T:M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1} \cr
   &= -vu^T:2\xi\,M^{-1}DM^{-1}\,d\xi \cr
   &= -2\xi\,(vu^T:M^{-1}DM^{-1})\,d\xi \cr
   &= -2\xi\,\operatorname{tr}\big(uv^TM^{-1}DM^{-1}\big)\,d\xi \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\xi} &= -2\xi\,\operatorname{tr}\big(uv^TM^{-1}DM^{-1}\big)  \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero, produces the trivial solution $$\xi=0$$
The trace-term will be zero only in the limit $|\xi|\rightarrow\infty\,\,\,$ in which case $M^{-1}\rightarrow(D^{-1}/\xi^2)\rightarrow 0$.

Note that the Frobenius product is related to the trace by $$A:B=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: Can you explain why the trace term is only zero in the limit that $|\xi| \to \infty$?  Thanks!

Comment: Oh I see, that is a trace of a product of an invertible matrix with a rank-1 matrix, so it's product is rank-1.  A rank-1 matrix has only one nonzero eigenvalue, so the sum of its eigenvalues, which equals the trace, could never be 0.  Is that correct?

Comment: Actually, hm there's no guarantee that a rank-1 matrix will have a nonzero eigenvalue... when I plot $f'(\xi)$, I find a root at $\xi \ne 0$.  I've checked over my numerics many times and I don't think it's wrong...